# Find and remove rows that are identical in 3 columns and differ in 1

Tags: r

I have binned my data in intervals (of 100000) using 2 different frames: from 0 to 100000 and onwards, and from 50000 to 150000 and onwards. I then joined both dataframes, using one column as identifier for the frames (represented in column "x100kb").

For my purpose, if 2 rows *(edit: they don't need to be sequent to each other; since the data is not ordered by "chr" and "x100kb" right now)* differ in "x100kb" by 0.5 (preferably comparing whole numbers to their +0.5; eg: 60 to 60.5, 65 to 65.5; etc) but they have the same values in "chr" and "occurrences_norm" and "occurrences_tum"; then they are equal and I want to remove one of them. The only thing coming to mind now are loops, which obviusly is not very productive...

Data example:

```
       chr    x100Kb occurrences_norm    occurrences_tum   fold
19064 chr17   61.5               17               0 14.05333
38799  chr5  526.0               16               0 13.96587
38800  chr5  526.5               16               0 13.96587
39946  chr5 1113.5               16               0 13.96587
2377   chr1 1426.0               15               0 13.87277
21859 chr18  733.5               15               0 13.87277
20538 chr18   24.0               14               0 13.77324
21863 chr18  735.5               14               0 13.77324
37699  chr4 1835.5               14               0 13.77324
39924  chr5 1102.5               14               0 13.77324
21506 chr18  550.5               13               0 13.66633
21862 chr18  735.0               13               0 13.66633
22258 chr19  151.5               13               0 13.66633
38972  chr5  613.0               13               0 13.66633
41707  chr6  194.5               13               0 13.66633
2380   chr1 1427.5               12               0 13.55087
20541 chr18   25.5               12               0 13.55087
21252 chr18  421.0               12               0 13.55087
27384  chr2 2243.0               12               0 13.55087
39990  chr5 1135.5               12               0 13.55087
```

In the example, the 3rd row would be removed.

Answer (score 2):

I read the question in a different way. I thought we need to compare any two sequent rows. For example, check row 1 & 2, row 2 & 3, and so on. I also thought that the condition is the difference in x100Kb is 0.5, not large than 0.5. I thought running four logical checks, using `shift()`, would be one way to achieve the goal.

```
setDT(df1)[!((abs(x100Kb - shift(x100Kb, type = "lag", fill = -Inf)) == 0.5) &
             (chr == shift(chr, type = "lag")) &
             (occurrences_norm == shift(occurrences_norm, type = "lag")) &
             (occurrences_tum == shift(occurrences_tum, type = "lag")))
           ]

#      chr x100Kb occurrences_norm occurrences_tum     fold
# 1: chr17   61.5               17               0 14.05333
# 2:  chr5  526.0               16               0 13.96587
# 3:  chr5 1113.5               16               0 13.96587
# 4:  chr1 1426.0               15               0 13.87277
# 5: chr18  733.5               15               0 13.87277
# 6: chr18   24.0               14               0 13.77324
# 7: chr18  735.5               14               0 13.77324
# 8:  chr4 1835.5               14               0 13.77324
# 9:  chr5 1102.5               14               0 13.77324
#10: chr18  550.5               13               0 13.66633
#11: chr18  735.0               13               0 13.66633
#12: chr19  151.5               13               0 13.66633
#13:  chr5  613.0               13               0 13.66633
#14:  chr6  194.5               13               0 13.66633
#15:  chr1 1427.5               12               0 13.55087
#16: chr18   25.5               12               0 13.55087
#17: chr18  421.0               12               0 13.55087
#18:  chr2 2243.0               12               0 13.55087
#19:  chr5 1135.5               12               0 13.55087
```

Answer (score 1):

We could also the `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[df1[,  .I[abs(x100Kb - shift(x100Kb, fill = -Inf)) > 0.5]  , 
                  by =  .(chr, occurrences_norm, occurrences_tum)]$V1]
#      chr x100Kb occurrences_norm occurrences_tum     fold
# 1: chr17   61.5               17               0 14.05333
# 2:  chr5  526.0               16               0 13.96587
# 3:  chr5 1113.5               16               0 13.96587
# 4:  chr1 1426.0               15               0 13.87277
# 5: chr18  733.5               15               0 13.87277
# 6: chr18   24.0               14               0 13.77324
# 7: chr18  735.5               14               0 13.77324
# 8:  chr4 1835.5               14               0 13.77324
# 9:  chr5 1102.5               14               0 13.77324
#10: chr18  550.5               13               0 13.66633
#11: chr18  735.0               13               0 13.66633
#12: chr19  151.5               13               0 13.66633
#13:  chr5  613.0               13               0 13.66633
#14:  chr6  194.5               13               0 13.66633
#15:  chr1 1427.5               12               0 13.55087
#16: chr18   25.5               12               0 13.55087
#17: chr18  421.0               12               0 13.55087
#18:  chr2 2243.0               12               0 13.55087
#19:  chr5 1135.5               12               0 13.55087
```

Comment: Is grouping a matter here? I am reading the question in the way that the OP is asking comparison of two sequent rows without grouping.

Comment: @jazzurro The line `but they have the same values in "chr" and "occurrences_norm" and "occurrences_tum";` seems like the OP wants to group it.

Comment: I see. I rather think that he/she is saying that if the difference in x100Kb = 0.5 for any two sequent rows, and if "cur", "occurrences_norm" and "occurrences_tum" are also identical between the rows, remove either of them.

Comment: @jazzurro Thanks for the input.  I am trying to think about that logic.  Suppose we created an index `setDT(df1)[,  i1 := abs(x100Kb - shift(x100Kb, fill = -Inf)) > 0.5]` without grouping, then do we need a second comparison as well?

Comment: @jazzurro Can you post your solution as well

Comment: Thanks for your input. @jazzurro is right, although the rows don't need to be sequent. Apologies for not clarifying that; although I guess I could order them by "chr" and "x100kb" and then do the comparison.

Comment: @TamaraDominguezPoncelas Thanks for your reply. You want to revise your question so that whoever seems the question can clearly understand what you are trying to do. That will help future viewers too.

Comment: @TamaraDominguezPoncelas Seeing your edit, do you want to group your data by `chr`?

Comment: @jazzurro No, that's not needed. The data was originally grouped by `chr`, by I modified it. What I need is the dataframe, ordered from higher to lower `fold`, erasing the rows mentioned before (comparing `x100kb` x.0 with x.5; if same `chr`, `occurrences_norm` and `occurrences_tum`; remove x.5).

Comment: @TamaraDominguezPoncelas Off to bed on this side of the Earth. I'll reply to you tomorrow.

Comment: @TamaraDominguezPoncelas I read your comment. So that means, your data in your question is arranged already since `fold` in in the order you want. Then, what you do is to compare two sequent rows. Am I still missing your point?

Answer (score 0):

Try this using `dplyr` package

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% group_by(chr,occurrences_norm,occurrences_tum) %>% 
mutate(tmp=diff(c(0,x100Kb))) %>% filter(tmp>0.5) %>% select(-tmp)

# chr x100Kb occurrences_norm occurrences_tum     fold
# (fctr)  (dbl)            (int)           (int)    (dbl)
# 1   chr17   61.5               17               0 14.05333
# 2    chr5  526.0               16               0 13.96587
# 3    chr5 1113.5               16               0 13.96587
# 4    chr1 1426.0               15               0 13.87277
# 5   chr18  733.5               15               0 13.87277
# 6   chr18   24.0               14               0 13.77324
# 7   chr18  735.5               14               0 13.77324
# 8    chr4 1835.5               14               0 13.77324
# 9    chr5 1102.5               14               0 13.77324
# 10  chr18  550.5               13               0 13.66633
# 11  chr18  735.0               13               0 13.66633
# 12  chr19  151.5               13               0 13.66633
# 13   chr5  613.0               13               0 13.66633
# 14   chr6  194.5               13               0 13.66633
# 15   chr1 1427.5               12               0 13.55087
# 16  chr18   25.5               12               0 13.55087
# 17  chr18  421.0               12               0 13.55087
# 18   chr2 2243.0               12               0 13.55087
# 19   chr5 1135.5               12               0 13.55087
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have tried this and seems to work. Would you mind explaining the code to me? I don't get this bit: `mutate(tmp=diff(c(0,x100Kb)))`

Comment: @TamaraDominguezPoncelas `mutate` will add a new variable named **tmp** which is calculated by taking iterative difference of `x100Kb` series using `diff` function.